# PHP GDChart installation failed

Tags: php, pecl

I want to install GD Chart on my local system (localhost).
I tried to install the GD Chart on localhost.

When I try to install through the following steps:

1. go to console mode
2. type : pecl install gdchart-0.2.0

It says:

```
pecl/gdchart requireds PHP extension "gd"
No valid packages found
install failed
```